# module mxnet has no attribute nd

Tags: pip, mxnet, gluonts

I am trying to use gluonts library. I installed gluonts 0.12.2 and when I try to import gluonts it says 'module mxnet has no attribute nd'. mxnet was installed by dependence with version 1.6.0. I am using macos, m1 pro. how can I solve this problem?

I tried to install mxnet from github repo and without dependence install, tried to install from pip with "pip install -U mxnet". they did not work.